# getElementsByClassName returns class names that contain specified name

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am using document.getElementsByClassName('example'), but it also returns classes where the specified parameter is a substring.
For example, it would also return an element where the classname is 'other example'. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: js doesn't have a built-in way to do this. You will need to loop through the returned elements and do some old-fashioned `==` or regex comparison. Alternatively, frameworks like jQuery make this easier

Comment: class names cannot contain spaces. If you classname contains a space it will be treated as a separate class.

Comment: @scrappedcola problem is natively classes are just like e.g. `class="foo bar"` and `getElementsByClassName` basically just does an `.indexOf` match on that full string. So you can totally do `getElementsByClassName('foo b')` and it will return if you happen to have an element with two classes `class="foo bar"`. Which is obviously not desired!

Comment: but @scrappedcola 's point is if you get "other example" returned, what you are really getting an element with *two separate classes* one is your "example" and it also has "other" as a separate class. So if you marked up an html element as "other example" as a class, expecting that to be a single class name, well that's not how it works

Comment: @CrayonViolent That's not true.  To test it, open your console right here on this page.  The body tag has `class="question-page new-topbar"`.  Run `document.getElementsByClassName("question-page new-topba")`, with the last letter cut off, and you get no elements.

Comment: @Josiah: Not sure I see your point. How does that contradict the comment you are referring to?

Comment: @FelixKling Crayon Violent said, "you can totally do `getElementsByClassName('foo b')`" and it will match an element with `class="foo bar"`.  That's not true, and you can easily test it on this very page.

Comment: @Josiah: Oh, I only looked at the previous comment. Makes sense now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing broken; you're selecting for any elements with the "example" class. `class="other example"` means an element has both "example" *and* "other".

If you want to retrieve elements with *only* one class, and your browser [supports `querySelectorAll`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector)*, you can use that, like so:

```js
var exact = document.querySelectorAll('[class="example"]');

for ( var i = 0; i < exact.length; ++i )
  exact[i].style.fontWeight = 'bold';
```

```html
<p class="example">example only</p>
<p class="other example">... and other</p>
```

* *Which it does, if it also supports `getElementsByClassName`*

Answer (score 0):

If your element class name is "other example" it means that your element has 2 classes. Try to name your classes with '-' or "_" like "other_example" or "other-example".