# getElementsByClassName returns duplicate elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, getelementsbyclassname

Looking more for an explanation rather than solving a problem. I return 4 items from:

`var inputFields = document.getElementsByClassName("calc-input-url");`

but when I log the array as output I get this:

```
[
    input#tippedEmployees.form-control.calc-input-url,
    input#hourlyWage.form-control.calc-input-url, 
    input#weeklyTips.form-control.calc-input-url, 
    input#hoursTippedEmp.form-control.calc-input-url, 
    tippedEmployees: input#tippedEmployees.form-control.calc-input-url,
    hourlyWage: input#hourlyWage.form-control.calc-input-url, 
    weeklyTips: input#weeklyTips.form-control.calc-input-url, 
    hoursTippedEmp: input#hoursTippedEmp.form-control.calc-input-url, 
    item: function…
]
```

I then logged the length of the array to double-check and only got a return value of 4.

Where do these extra elements in the array come from, and why are they there/how can I make use of them (if at all)?

Comment: `document.getQuerySelectorAll('input.calc-input-url')` might be better if you just want the input elements.

Comment: @Andy Tested and that does work as an alternative method, however it is `document.querySelectorAll()`. I did think of that alternate method via this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056479/getelementsbyclassname-returns-class-names-that-contain-specified-name). I didn't think that would work because of multiple classes for one input but it does. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see there is not a regular array, but an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). The fact that the array "has keys" (`tippedEmployees:`) should be a giveaway that this is no ordinary array. The `HTMLCollection` exposes the elements in an array-like manner, but also directly via their ids. This is a convenience for you.

In practice there should be no problems, since you're *either* going to iterate the "array part" of it using `for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) list[i]...`, *or* you're going to access the elements directly by id.